# Filter data frame using condition

Tags: python, pandas

i have created a data frame like this:

```
d = {"one":[1,2,3],"two":[[["c",3],["a",4]],["b",5],["a",6]]}
pd.DataFrame(d)
```

My question is: how do i filter out a new data frame that column "two" contains only "a"

[image: Expected result]

Comment: Please show us what you think the results should look like with this data.

Comment: thank you @piRSquared i've just added the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you :

```
df.loc[df["two"].astype(str).str.contains("a")]
```

Comment: this answer is clean and neat. Vote for this answer to be the correct answer. I was also thinking using `apply` method, however, `apply` is expensive.

Comment: Thank you that could help me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) method to return a mask of booleans, which can be used to select the correct indexes. The idea is to define a function that you want to act on each element of the `Series` and apply that (using `apply`) to the entire series.

```
def fun(element):
    print(element)
    if type(element[0])==list:
        l=[e[0]=='a' for e in element]
    else:
        l = [element[0]=='a']

    if True in l:
        return True
    else:
        return False

df[df.two.apply(fun)]
```

Comment: The other answer gives same result but is more elegant. Use it. This can be seen as an alternative solution if one insists on using apply

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)